# Segmentation Error 11 in C while writing a file to disk and using buffers

Tags: c, audio, segmentation-fault, buffer

This program is designed to create an output sine wave file with user inputs for duration, amplitude, sampling rate and frequency, filling a buffer with values and applying an short attack and decay ramp before writing a new .aiff file with the data.

Although my program compiles fine, it runs into a 'Segmentation Error 11' when ran with arguments, which after some quick googling seems linked to running out of memory. I've checked my code several times (mainly the areas that deal with the buffer size and pointers to it).

```
   /* playsine.c */
/* Creates a sine wave audio file with input outfile - duration - amplitude - sampling 
    rate - frequency */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <portsf.h>

int makeSine(float *buffer, double amplitude, long numFrames, double sineFreq,
             double samplingPeriod){
    long i;
    double time;
    double twoPi = 2 * M_PI;
    for(i = 0, time = 0; i < numFrames; i++){
        buffer[i] = amplitude * sin(twoPi * sineFreq * time);
        time += samplingPeriod;
        }
    return i;
    }



   long attack(float *buffer, long attackFrames){
    long i = 0;
    double factor = 0.0, increment = 1.0/attackFrames;
    while(factor <= 1.0 && i < attackFrames){
        buffer[i] = factor * buffer[i];
        factor += increment;
        ++i;
        }
    return i;
    }

long decay(float *endBuffer, long decayFrames){
    long i = 0;
    double factor = 1.0, decrement = 1.0/decayFrames;
    while(factor >= 0.0 && i < decayFrames){
        endBuffer[i] = decayFrames * endBuffer[i];
        factor -= decrement;
        ++i;
        }
    return i;
    }

enum {nameArg, outArg, durArg, ampArg, sampArg, freqArg, numArg};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    if(argc < numArg){
        printf("Usage:\toutfile.aiff\tduration(s)\tamplitude(0-1)\tsampling rate\t\
        frequency(hz)\n");
        return 1;
        }
    if(psf_init()){
        printf("Error: Unable to open portsf library\n");
        return 1;
        }

    PSF_PROPS props;
    int outfile;
    long numFrames, samplingRate = atol(argv[sampArg]);
    double amps = atof(argv[ampArg]), samplingPeriod = 1.0/samplingRate;
    double sineFreq = atof(argv[freqArg]), attackFrames = 0.005 * samplingRate;
    double decayFrames = 0.01 * samplingRate;
    float *buffer, duration = atof(argv[durArg]);   
    numFrames = (long)duration * samplingRate;
    float *endBuffer = buffer + (numFrames - (long)decayFrames);

//Fill structure    
    props.srate = samplingRate;
    props.chans = 1;
    props.samptype = PSF_SAMP_16;
    props.format = PSF_AIFF;
    props.chformat = MC_MONO;


//Assign buffer
    buffer = (float*)malloc(numFrames * props.chans * sizeof(float));
    if(buffer == 0){
        printf("Error: unable to allocate buffer\n");
        return 1;
    }else{
//Fill buffer
        if(makeSine(buffer, amps, numFrames, sineFreq, samplingPeriod) != numFrames){
            printf("Error: unable to create sinewave\n");
            return 1;
            }
        attack(buffer, attackFrames);
        decay(endBuffer, decayFrames);
        }

//Create an outfile
    outfile = psf_sndCreate(argv[outArg], &props, 0, 0, PSF_CREATE_RDWR);
    if(outfile < 0){
        printf("Error: unable to create %s\n", argv[outArg]);
        return 1;
        }
//Write buffer to file          
    printf("Writing %s ...\n", argv[outArg]);
    if(psf_sndWriteFloatFrames(outfile, buffer, numFrames) != numFrames){
        printf("Warning: error writing %s\n", argv[outArg]);
        return 1;
        }
//Close file    
    if(psf_sndClose(outfile)){
        printf("Warning: error closing %s\n", argv[outArg]);
        return 1;
        }

    psf_finish();
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: What are the inputs that work and what inputs cause the crash?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question; previously (without the attack and decay functions), the program worked fine with all arguments and outputted the correct file and format, its just with the new 'attack' and 'decay' functions it crashes. Sorry, I should  have worded my question a bit better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two immediate problems that I see in `decay()` and `attack()`:

```
long attack (float *buffer, long attackFrames) {
    long i;
    ...
        buffer[i] = factor * buffer[i];  //Oops, i is never initialized
```

The variable `i` is never initialized. This is undefined behaviour and could well lead to crashes. I assume you actually wanted to do something like:

```
long attack (float *buffer, long attackFrames) {
    long i = 0;
    double factor = 0.0, increment = 1.0/attackFrames;

    while(factor <= 1.0 && i < attackFrames) {
        buffer[i] = factor * buffer[i];
        factor += increment;
        ++i;
    }

    return i;
}
```

**Edit:** Another problem is you reference uninitialized memory with `endBuffer`:

```
 float *buffer;              // Buffer not initialized
 float *endBuffer = buffer + (numFrames - (long)decayFrames);  // Oops!
 ...
 buffer = (float*)malloc(numFrames * props.chans * sizeof(float)); 
 //endBuffer still points to buffer's original address which is who-knows-where
```

You should assign `endBuffer` after you use `malloc()` to allocate `buffer`.

Comment: Yeah, I applied your advice (which I would have needed to for the loops to interact with the buffer), but it still returns the error.

Comment: Added another problem with `endBuffer`. Note I would need your command line inputs to actually test the code.

Comment: I'll try your amendments in a moment - the inputs I've been testing with are `./playsine 10 1 44100 1000`